# Delphi - импорт таблицы из запароленого ACCESS файла

Tags: access, ado, delphi

Прекрасно работает следующая конструкция импорта таблицы из внешнего незапароленного *.mdb файла:

```
INSERT INTO tabl SELECT * FROM tabl IN "C:\1.mdb"
```

А вот если файл запаролен - вылетает ошибка EOleException - 'Ошибочный пароль'
Как в строке передать pasw? Конструкция

```
INSERT INTO tabl SELECT * FROM tabl IN "C:\1.mdb" [Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123]
```

не работает.

Comment: Ищу родное решение. Например для DBF параметры могут передаваться так: 
Query1.SQL.Add('Select * FROM price IN '+''''+'C:\'+''''+'[dBase IV;HDR=NO;IMEX=2]'); 
А вот как передается PWD для mdb?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй указать пароль в самом ADOConnection

ДаблКлик по ADOConnection -> Use Connection String -> BUILD ->
в свойствах связи с данными вкладка подключение

Answer (score 0):

Если пароль к этой базе известен на этапе разработки, то предлагаю создать добавить ADOConnection (для запароленной БД, у него в окне настроек, которое появляется после двойного клика, на закладке "Все" (All) будет список свойств, выбрать свойство JetOLEDB: Database Password, нажать кнопку "Изменить значение" и в появившееся окно вписать пароль файла БД) связать с ним запрос ADOQuery, а при переносе из той БД в требуемую, запрашивать пароль у пользователя, предварительно сохранив его в строковой переменной (пароль можно выдрать из свойства ADOConnection ConnectionString с помощью функций для работы со строками).

Comment: Спасибо. Я знаю как программно подключиться к бд с паролем, я ищу именно способ быстрого обмена между двумя запароленными файлами. Если прямой импорт из запароленного файла не возможен, может есть возможность быстрого обмена между двумя ADOConnection? Через переменные не подходит, большое кол-во полей, которые к тому же могут меняться.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте у ADOConnection указать поле loginpromt в False

Answer (score 0):

Не устраивайте фарш. Прежде чем использовать БД к ней надо подключиться, укажите параметры подключения в т.ч. пароль и потом указывайте запрос. Не надо путать "зарос к БД" и "подключение к БД". Есть ситуации когда некоторые компоненты, вместе со строкой запроса используют параметры подключения(и обычно это не указывается в строке запроса, а пишется как отдельный параметр), но насколько знаю Delphi не обладает такой способностью, во всяком случае стандартные компоненты.